# sql connection settings via web config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, database-connection

I've defined my connection string as ::

```
<add name="ammyGroupConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ammyGroup_Server;Initial Catalog=ammyGroup_Staging;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ammyGroup;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="ammyGroupConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ammyGroup_Server;Initial Catalog=ammyGroup_Staging;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ammyGroup;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Now in the file there are tags,

```
 <location allowOverride="true" inheritInChildApplications="true">
    <appSettings>
    <add key="DBSchema" value=/>
<add key="DBUserId" value=/>
<add key="DBPassword" value=/>
<add key="DBServerName" value=/>
<add key="DBName" value=/>
```

1. What does these keys are? What should be the value of these keys? Please explain.

I know that the keys

> add key="DBUserId" and  add key="DBPassword"

are for MS SQL SERVER user name and password but what **when there is windows authentication only**? Please explain.

I know for windows authentication we have to do ::

> Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;

but what about **appsetting** values

Comment: Who defined those tags ? Are they being used in application ?

Comment: sorry I do not know. the project was handover to me.